# The page must show the values in the fields which are previously submitted

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a form with 3 fields. 2 fields are dropdowns and one text box.

Once i submit the data, it is inserted into DB and the page is redirected to the same form.
Now, the redirected form must show the values in the fields which were previously selected.

It is a struts based application.

Answer (score 0):

cache the entered value in the form and using set it into field